# What organic solvents are suitable to use with potassium permanganate?

Tags: solvents

I'm attempting to oxidize a substance with potassium permanganate and I was wondering what organic solvents I have at my disposal. The compound is soluble in chloroform and ethanol, but obviously those would not do well with a powerful oxidizing agent. The phase-transfer catalyst I'm going to employ is tetra-n-butylammonium bromide.

Comment: Since your compound is soluble in chloroform, is it also soluble in methylene chloride? I found a reference showing good solubility of tetra-n-butylammonium permanganate in that solvent. Other chlorinated solvents, such as 1,1,2,-trichloroethane were mentioned in another article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you need a solvent that 1) does not react with KMnO<sub>4</sub> and 2) is immiscible with water.

As @Janice DelMar said in her comment, some of the lower-chlorinated hydrocarbons (methylene chloride, 1,2-dichloroethane, 1,1,2-trichloroethane) should work. If you can live with a high boiling point solvent, you might consider chlorobenzene.

Other solvents that fit these criteria include most alkanes (pentane, hexane, cyclohexane, petroleum ether, etc.), benzene (but not toluene), and diethyl ether.

A quick test to determine compatibility of your solvent with KMnO<sub>4</sub> involves a TLC stain. Make (or borrow) a batch of [KMnO<sub>4</sub> stain as described here](http://orgprepdaily.wordpress.com/2006/09/27/tlc-staining-solutions/). Dip a TLC plate into your solvent and then dip it into the stain with minimal drying between. If the plate turns brown (MnO<sub>2</sub>), then your solvent was oxidized and is no good. If the plate stays purple, then your solvent is resistant.

Comment: Love the KMnO4 stain tip!